# Event for playing an Audiofile using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I'd like to change my background whenever i press the playbutton for an audiofile, which event do i use for it? As Background im using a divbox which i fade out and in

```
#Background {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that on your page you have a button ... for example:

```
<button id="play">Play</button>
```

When the button is clicked, it causes an event that can be trapped and handled:

```
$("#play").click(function() {
   // do something here
});
```

You have the ability to add a CSS class to an element using:

```
$(... selector ...).addClass("className");
```

which will cause the restyling of the element associated with the new class.

If the event source is a media file, it may be coded as:

```
<source id="mySource" src="...file..." ...></source>
```

In which case, you can capture a play event with:

```
$("#mySource").on("play", function() {
   // do something here
});
```

Comment: I ment something like this: <!DOCTYPE html>
`code` <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">`code`